# For some reason its giving me undefined undefined undefined inthis code

Tags: javascript

```js
class cars {
  construtor(name, color, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.type = type;
  }

  brand(br) {
    console.log(this.name + " " + this.color + " " + this.type)
  }
}
const type1 = new cars("ferrari", "red", "Automatic");
console.log(type1)

type1.brand()

class cars2 extends cars {
  ask(text) {
    this.brand(text)
  }

}

const type2 = new cars2("BMW", "Blue", "Automatic")
type2.ask()
```

so i wanted it to give out the following things i wrote in consts but it gives me undefined 3 times on both.

Comment: Should `construtor` be `constructor`? Your console should give a good idea where the error is.

Comment: Just a quick note, classes usually start with a capital letter, so `class Car` instead of `class car`

Comment: @user1599011 How would the console identify this error? There's no error when a class has no constructor. Misspelling "constructor" just means it never gets called.

Comment: @user15990011 it hardly would give any error, since it's interpreted as a common method of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Simply it's misspelling `construtor` should be `constructor`

```js
class cars {
  constructor(name, color, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.type = type;
  }

  brand(br) {
    console.log(this.name + " " + this.color + " " + this.type)
  }
}
const type1 = new cars("ferrari", "red", "Automatic");
console.log(type1)

type1.brand()

class cars2 extends cars {
  constructor(name, color, type) {
    super(name, color, type);
  } 

  ask(text) {
    this.brand(text)
  }

}

const type2 = new cars2("BMW", "Blue", "Automatic")
type2.ask()
```

Comment: Also, when you are extending, you should invoke `super` and pass the necessary parameters to the parent class. In case, parent is `Cars`

Comment: @AnindyaDey You are right. Thanks :)